# Como hacer un post request en una aplicacion MVC para hacer una integracion a un web services?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jsonp

```
    //
    // GET: /Asientos/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Asientos/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(Asientos asientos)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Asientos.Add(asientos);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(asientos);
    }
```

Comment: Bienvenido Ramon! Me gustaría entender con más detalle qué estás preguntando. ¿Podrías [edit] la pregunta para que quede claro qué estás intentando hacer, en dónde está fallando en concreto y qué punto en particular te interesa resolver? Gracias!

Comment: Saludos Mariano, lo que intento es enviar la información de mi formulario a una URL. Lo que se busca es integrar las aplicaciones con la informacion que envio, estoy usando MVC me gustaria saber como envio dicha informacion. Basicamente lo que tengo que hacer es un post a un servicio web y pasar u body json, me gustaria saber como hacer esto en MVC.

Comment: El post lo podes hacer con ajax, pero faltarían mas datos, como el formulario que vas a enviar y que espera el servicio. salutes.

Comment: Aqui te muestro el formulario https://drive.google.com/open?id=1edN8drytFLPwezFlyfqTAOpzo60Az8GTRoS5_GbM-e4

Answer (score 1):

Si entendi bien necesitas invocar usando jquery un action del controller pasando los datos por POST, si es asi podrias implementar

[¿Pasando objetos JSON a los Action Methods MVC4?](https://www.gittprogram.com/question/250772_pasando-objetos-json-a-los-action-methods-mvc4.html)

fijate en el articulo como define el json que envia en el data del $.ajax para que model binding mapee este con las propiedades de la clase que dfines por parametro.

lo importante es como definir en codigo cliente el `$.ajax`

```
var obj = { .. }; //aqui json equivalente a la clase que defines como parametro del action
$.ajax(
{
       url: '@Url.Action("Create","NombreCtrl")',
       type: "POST",
       cache: false,
       dataType: "json",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       data: JSON.stringify(obj),
       success: function (data) {
           //codigo
      },
      error: function () {
           alert("error");
      }
 });
})
```

En este otro se explica un poco mas paso a paso

[Calling ASP MVC Controllers from jQuery Ajax](http://www.makeitspendit.com/calling-asp-mvc-controllers-from-jquery-ajax/)